# Different domain redirect to different folder in root directory in hosting

Tags: asp.net

I have hosting for my ASP.NET apps.
I have 3x aliases of domain:

```
example.com
second.com
superexample.com
```

I need to help with redirecting peoples in different applications.

- People from example.com will be redirected to root/example.com folder, where will be my Asp.net application.
- People from second.com will be redirected to root/second.com folder, where will be my next Asp.net application.
- Etc.

How to implement this?
And what's about the SEO?
Isn't it a problem for google to make this applications as different?
And after redirecting will be links like this: example.com/products.aspx for example.com folder and second.com/products.aspx for second.com folder?

Answer (score 2):

1. Application URL re-writing:

   - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx
   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx
2. IIS rewriting:

   - http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/
3. Proxy rewriting

   - http://forums.iis.net/t/1157355.aspx
   - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/squid-url-rewriting-676928/